# Any random variable, does tail of integral goes to 0?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}$ real.
(Not necessarily $\mathbf{E}|X| < \infty$, also if it is the case, the below is true).
Let $\mathbf{P}(|X| = \infty) = 0$.
Can we say the following holds?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{a \to \infty} \mathbf{E}\left[|X|\textbf{I}(|X|>a) \right]
= \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{|x|>a} |x| dF_X(x) = \int_{|x|=\infty} |x| dF_X(x)
= 0.
\end{equation}
At first, I thought this is true because integration on the probability zero (measure zero set).
But I am not sure because of the following example.

Let $X$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{N}$ with 
$\textbf{P}(X = n) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{n^2}$.
Then for any $a$, we have 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}[|X|\textbf{I}(|X|>a)] = \sum_{n = a}^\infty \frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{n} = \infty
\end{equation}
However how we interpret the limit? That is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{a \to \infty} \sum_{n = a}^\infty \frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n = \infty}^\infty \frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{n} = 0 ?
\end{equation}
But I am not sure whether it makes sense taking limit on the value of $\infty$.
Then I feel like to say that the above doesn't have limit. But I am not strongly sure.
I think there is a missing part that I don't know and maybe an elementary reason. Any comments, suggestions, answers will be very appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'd look at the [Cauchy Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) - looks like a counter example at first sight.

Comment: @AlexR Thank you for your comment. I noticed that the mean of Cauchy is not defined! Based on pdf of Cauchy, my discrete example contains the similar property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct. You have $f(a)=\mathbf{E}[|X|\mathbf{I}(|X|>a)]=\infty$
for all $a$ and hence $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}f(a)=\infty\neq 0.$

The only point of confusion you seem to be left with is the symbol $\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}$.
While this symbol does not have a standard interpretation, the only reasonable interpretation would be $$\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}g(n)\equiv\lim_{\ell\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=\ell}^{u}g(n).$$
However, I would just avoid from using $\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}$ altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. I was confused with that symbol. Now things are clear. Thanks!